# how to change iis log location remotely using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I need some help with the following.
I have to remotely change IIS log location for a list of IIS servers.

locally i can do it using:

Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -name logFile.directory -value 'loglocation'

i need some advice on how to run this command on multiple IIS hosts remotely.
Could you give me some guidance please?

Something like:

$hosts = get-content 'path'
foreach ($computer in $hosts)

{
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -name logFile.directory -value 'loglocation'
}
but somehow in Set-itempropriety to specify the $computer.
I've read about something about - pspath but not sure if this helps.
Thanks

Comment: `Invoke-Command` will be your friend here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-Command` for that:

```
$Hosts = @("Host1", "Host")
$LogPath = "xyz"

foreach($Host in $Hosts)
{
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Host -ScriptBlock { 
       'Your code here'
       Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -name logFile.directory -value $using:LogPath
   }
}
```

If you need to use variables from the outer scope within your `Invoke-Command` ScriptBlock you can use `$using`

Answer (score 0):

thanks, that's it. it worked. Instead if -computerName I've used -session